# Sending SMS without SMTP header on PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to send a SMS verification code through PHP using following code which is working for me

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
$from = "WebMapper";
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$EmailTo = "2222222222@msg.telus.com";
$Subject = "";
$message = "Code is : 54689";
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

but I am getting `domain@p39966pn2222.prod.phx3.secureserve Subj:` line at the top of SMS too!

> **domain@p39966pn2222.prod.phx3.secureserve Subj:**
>
> Code is : 54689

I tried to not get this by adding a

```
$from = "WebMapper";
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
```

but still getting it on top of the text message. How can I overwrite or get rid of it and just send the

> Code is : 54689

without SMTP header?

Comment: I would avoid using email to sms.  I have done it myself countless times and it usually ends up being inconstant.  Now I use Twilio to send my SMS's, they have a PHP SDK and is really easy to use, but it does cost $0.01/message. https://www.twilio.com/

Comment: Is this an Email to SMS service provided by Telus? If so it may not be possible to stop the header as it's part of the sending process and they are adding it.

Comment: @AndyC, thanks for reply but this looks more like the Godaddy SMTP account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing `\r\n` from `$headers`, you end the SMTP headers prematurely.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for reply, I updated the code to `$headers = 'From: WebMapper' ;` as you said but still getting same header at SMS

Comment: Strange it sure looks like a superfluous `\r\n`. Can you check the SMTP traffic to verify if the error is on your side or happening on the email-to-sms gateways side?

Comment: It is working but I am still getting the last part `Subj:` !

Comment: The correct header would be `Subject:`, I wonder where Subj: is coming from