# SMS contains incorrect meta-information when sending with PHP

Tags: php, sms

I am trying to send SMS through PHP by using this code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');
$errorMSG = "";
$headers .= "";
$headers .= "From: info@xxxxxxxxx.ca";
$EmailTo = "2222222222@msg.telus.com";
$Subj = "\r\n Thanks For Schduling Appointment With Us \r\n";
$message = " Your Secure Code is : 54689";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subj, $message, $headers);
```

which is working OK for me but I am having some issues here:

1. Message is added a string **Subj:** which is not in the code! how can I get rid of it?
2. the Sender Number looks `99999999` how can I force to display my actual number instead of that fake number?
3. I tried to add new/break line by adding `\r\n` to the string but as you can see from the first tried SMS at took it as string as well. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: This looks extremely similar to a question yesterday. I think both of those items are handled by the Telus email to sms service and I don't think you can change them. Someone yesterday suggested using Twilio instead.

Comment: Oh it was you yesterday also :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989948/issue-on-sending-sms-without-smtp-header-on-php

Comment: I have no money to pay to Twilio Bro! :-(

Comment: Something strange does seem to be happening. I would take the `\r\n` off your subject. Also, if you change the name of your `$Subj` variable, does the content of the message change to reflect that?